# the types of flags to run an application in android

Tags: android

**please help me.**

- I want know about what types of flags to run an application in android. asked me in interview.

Comment: No problem. Which Android developer documentation pages did you review already? We don't want to waste your time by telling you the things you've already researched.

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT,
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK,
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP,
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET,
FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS,
FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT,
FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY,
FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK,
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK,
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION,
LAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY,
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION,
FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP,
FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT,
FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED,
FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP,
FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe they asked for the [launch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)? you can set that to ensure you never call a new activity if an old one is in the history stack.